# Cannot use import statement outside a module when using wrangler v2

Tags: cloudflare, wrangler

I'm new to using cloudflare and wrangler. I've a project that I've been working on, and I'm now trying to deploy it using `wrangler publish`, but I keep running into issues. My product is coded in node.js, and I'm using version 2 of wrangler. When I execute `wrangler publish` I get:

```
Basic JavaScript project found. Skipping unnecessary build!
Error: Something went wrong with the request to Cloudflare...
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
  at worker.js:2Basic JavaScript project found. Skipping unnecessary build!
Error: Something went wrong with the request to Cloudflare...
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
  at worker.js:2
```

I've searched for a solution, and one of them that I found said to change module in wrangler.toml from `type="javascript"`to `type="webpack"` however that gives me a bunch of errors:

```
 ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' ... Parsed request is a module...resolve as module
      /Users/Desktop/APIs/cpiCalculator2/node_modules/destroy/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
...
Error: webpack returned an error. You may be able to resolve this issue by running npm install.
```

I've tried reinstalling npm as it suggests and then `wrangler publish` again, but that just gives me the same error message.

I'm really not sure what the issue is, and I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Also, just a note, I'm not sure if this is affecting it, but I do have two other js documents in the main area of my project (where my index.js file is).